# CSS display: table-cell width 100% overflow-x expand

Tags: css, responsive-design, scrollbar, html-table

I have this two column layout, made with display: table and display: table-cell, and I want to put in the second column a div with horizontal scroll, but the table expands itself and the scroll goes to the entire page rather then the div.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque convallis finibus metus. Suspendisse commodo rutrum sapien, eu faucibus metus. Nunc elementum augue eu aliquet condimentum. 
    </div>
    <div id="two">
        <div id="horizontal">
            <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1218282/slideshow/1.jpg" />
            <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1218282/slideshow/2.jpg" />
            <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1218282/slideshow/3.jpg" />
            <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1218282/slideshow/4.jpg" />
        </div>        
   </div>        
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper { 
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
#one {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 200px;
}
#two { 
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
#horizontal {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#horizontal img {
     max-width: 200px;   
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cUCvY/2597/

In this example I'd like to have the horizontal scroll active on the div with the images inside and not on the page.

Comment: You have to fix the width of #horizontal this div!! try it

Answer (score 1):

Hope i understood correctly:

```
.wrapper { 
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:100%
}
#one {
   display: table-cell;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 200px;
}
#two { 
}
#horizontal {

    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#horizontal img {
     max-width: 200px;   
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   #one { 
    float: none;
    margin-right:0;
    width:auto;
    border:0;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000;    
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cUCvY/2600/